# Chrome storage API quota

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I read that there is a [quota limit](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-sync) while using [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage) API:

> QUOTA_BYTES: 102,400
>   The maximum total amount (in bytes) of data that can be stored in sync storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of every value plus every key's length. Updates that would cause this limit to be exceeded fail immediately and set runtime.lastError

The question is: will every user have 102400 bytes or is the quota limit global to all users?

Comment: Sync is per user so the quota is also per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference: the quota is per user.